iText7 PdfWriter Issue in Release Mode on Android - Works Fine in Debug Mode
Problem:
I'm developing a .NET MAUI app targeting Android using .NET Core 8. The app uses iText7 (version 8.0.5) to generate PDF files. The PDF generation works perfectly in debug mode, but when I switch to release mode, the PDF creation fails. Interestingly, this issue wasn't present with iText7 version 8.0.4.
Details:
iText7 Version: 8.0.5 (Issue does not occur in 8.0.4)
Development Environment:
IDE: Microsoft Visual Studio 17.10.5
Xamarin.Android SDK: 13.2.2.0
Target Android API: 34
.NET Version: .NET Core 8
Platform: MAUI app targeting Android
What I’ve Tried:
Checked the application code: There are no differences in the PDF generation logic between debug and release mode.
Reverting to an earlier version of iText7: The issue does not occur with version 8.0.4.
Analyzed build configurations: Ensured that the same settings are applied in both debug and release modes, but the problem persists in release mode.
Question:
What could be causing this issue with iText7 version 8.0.5 in release mode on Android? Are there any specific settings or configurations that I should check, or is this potentially a bug in the latest iText7 version?
Additional Information:
Logs: No specific errors are shown in the log files during PDF generation in release mode.
Build Configurations: Verified that the release and debug configurations are consistent.
Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions!

Could you add a minimal reproducible example?

Where is the relevant code?  Are there errors or exceptions?  Have you contacted iText support, or looked at their open bugs, or reported a bug to them?

@Guust I think is something in my code, because i ipdate itext to 8.0.5 in MauiPdfJsViewerSample and it works. My pdf generator code is much more complex.

@jason There ar no errors or exceptions, only a white screen where the pdf suppose to be. I haven't contact them, I looked for a similar problem with no luck.

For now I resolved the problem donwgrading itext7 to 8.0.4, thank you all

If you are still investigating this issue: "My pdf generator code is much more complex." - have you stored the generated PDFs in a location you can download them from? Then you should do so and analyze (are share here for us to analyze) those PDFs. Oftentimes such an analysis helps identifying where to look for the issue.
